regression when both dependent and independent are both censored
I wonder if there is any technique that measures association between two censored variables. I am given a dataset that includes result from two assays, both of which have a upper detection limit. The question is whether one assay is significantly associated with the other assay.
The tobit model seems to be a popular model when dependent variable is censored. I am not aware of any method for when both dependent and independent variables can be censored.
Any advise is appreciated.
Thanks,
Peter

Many years ago I asked a multivariate version of this question but to date haven't received (nor invented) an adequate answer, although some posts in that thread provide intriguing ideas.
